# Как обновить PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell

Здраствуйте. знаю такая тема уже создавалась, но она мне не помогла. нужно обновить PowerShell 2.0 на более новую. Net Framework установлен последний. WMF 5.0 (Windows Management Framework 5.0) не устанавливается. Запускаю файл ps1 через PowerShell пишет что "не удается загрузить файл, так как выполнение скриптов запрещена в данной системе"

PowerShell нужно обновить как я понял, так как не выполняется команда Add-Migration Initial в VS 2019.

Comment: "PowerShell нужно обновить как я понял, так как не выполняется команда Add-Migration Initial в VS 2019." Я так понимаю, речь идет о скрипте для Entity Framework? Проверьте, что у вас установлен пакет, содержащий эти скрипты. Для EF Core это то ли Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, то ли Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.

Comment: пытаюсь установить появляется две ошибки 1) Ошибка  Сбой при восстановлении пакета. Откат изменений пакета для «Shop». 2) Ошибка NU1605 Обнаружено понижение версии пакета Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore с 5.0.4 на 5.0.3. Чтобы выбрать другую версию, создайте ссылку на пакет напрямую из проекта. 
 Shop -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.4 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.4 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 5.0.4 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 5.0.4) 
 Shop -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 5.0.3) Shop D:\C# ASP.Net\Shop\Shop\Shop.csproj 1

Comment: Ошибка *"не удается загрузить файл, так как выполнение скриптов запрещена в данной системе"* говорит о том, что в системе запрещено выполнение скриптов, а не что надо что-то обновлять. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: хорошо. как мне решить вопрос обновления PowerShell? я когда ввожу в VS Add-Migration Initial появлятся ScriptHalted. в интернете поискал, пишут надо обновить PowerShell

Comment: Скачать установщик нового PowerShell и запустить его. ¿Нет?

Comment: @user7860670 Какой именно?

Comment: Какой хотите...

Comment: я пробовал то что есть на сайте Microsoft. не получается. WMF на прямую не устанавливается, скрипт через PS не запускается

Comment: ¿А при чем тут WMF, когда вы собрались powershell обновлять?

Comment: ну как пишут в интернете нужно установить net framework и windows management framework чтобы обновить poweshell.   net framework по умолчанию установлен вместе с VS, powershell версии 2,0. а wmf не устанавливается

Comment: Скачайте установщик нового PowerShell и запустите его... А то по факту вы ничего даже не попытались установить...

Comment: @user7860670 я уже все пытался сделать. я скачал powershell, разных версий. все требуют установки microsoft management framework от 4,0 версии. скачиваю версии 5,1 с оф сайта (Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.msu). не устанавливается. пишет "Выполняется установка обновлений", начинается какая то установка , потом все прекращается и надпись "Следующие обновления не установлены: Обновление для ОС Windows (KB3191566)
"

Comment: может проблема с операционкой. Windows 7, только надпись внизу экрана что копия не является подлинной

Comment: MS уже давно прекратили выпускать Powershell с поддержкой windows 7. Ну и обновления на пиратскую копию тоже накатить не удастся. В этом ничего удивительного нет.

Comment: я разговаривал сейчас с человеком кто мне ставил винду. говорит что не должно быть проблем с установкой. на оф сайте есть powershell для windows 7. только версии 5,1 последняя.  у меня 2,0. . вот как обновить. я уже целый день бьюсь везде одно и тоже пишут, ничего не помогает. или надо только на новую винду переходить?

Comment: Если бы windows была лицензионная, то, надо полагать, недостающие обновления установились бы. Но вообще да, Windows 7 уже все, причем уже давно. Та же powershell 5 вышла 5 лет назад. Используйте Windows 10 и powershell 7.1